# How to localize results from a database?

Tags: .net

I am localizing a legacy application (Winform app developed with VB.net) and on a few of the forms, results for account statuses are displayed directly to the user.

How can these words (that are stored in a database) be localized?  I've tried using resource files like how I did the rest of the application, but (not surprisingly) it didn't work.

Is there a general practice or way to go about translating items that come from a database and are not actually within the code or forms?

For example, in an XSLT in my solution I have the following:

```
      <xsl:attribute name="Session_State">
        <xsl:value-of select="@TSSS"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
```

That holds ~8 or so different session states that are all stored in a database that all need to be translated.  This is where resource files and the resource manager aren't doing the trick for me.

I am using Resx Manager to localize the rest of the application.  All strings are currently in resource files and the entire application translates except for this particular part and I'm unsure how to go about doing it.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, I'll show you how you can localize using DB

```
Table Language
---------------
languageId description       culture cultureId
1          American English  en-Us   0x0409 
2          Mexican Spanish   es-MX   0x080A  

Table StringMaster
------------------
stringId
1

Table StringLocal
------------------
stringId language text
1         1       name
1         2       nombre 

Table SystemUser
---------------
userId   Name          languageId
1        John Smith     1
2        Jesus Navas    2
```

In your code, you need to load application strings based on string id and user language. If this is web app, you can load and cache your metadata and select needed subsets from the memory for performance purposes. Same thing applies to desktop app.

Your code will look like this, on `form_load`, for example, setting the label

```
lblName.Text = localizer.GetString(1, "Name"); //1 - stringId; 
                                // "Name" - default value, if metadata call fails
```

when you construct your localizer, set the language

```
var localizer = new Localizer(currentUser.LanguageId);
```

There we go. This is just one of many methods.

Comment: Interesting.  Can this be applied to XSLT?  Check my edit to the question in a second.

Comment: I am not big on transformations. The beauty of my approach is that you have any language support without any recompilation, etc. Add new languages, and its representative strings to DB and you good to go. You can set your thread culture into as well, which is handy when you work with Excel docs, for example. Only when you have new string Ids, which means you have new controls, that you need to recompile. You don't have to think of this as an answer if it doesn't feet your strategy. My answer definitely oriented on in-code dynamic localization.

Comment: I'm all for that, the only problem is that this application was created long before I got a hold of it and we're not completely re-doing it, unfortunately.  I do appreciate the effort and I'll see what I can do.  Thanks!

Comment: how can this be use in winforms

Comment: @Smith It is winforms -- `lblName.Text = localizer.GetString(1, "Name");`

Comment: I have menuitem, buttons, DatagridviewColumns, etc each of which is a different type of component, did you have to assign the text for each manually?

Comment: **1**. The goal here is to make language changing based on user. In this case, this `localizer` does the job for you internally. So, yea, you need to add `myControl.text` for each control. **2** You can go further. like `foreach (var c in form.controls) localizer.SetText(c);`. In this case, you must set control tag or control name in specific way, so that parser can find out from control itself, which string to assign. The reason why #2 is not favorable, is because it is not clear where the stuff comes from when something goes wrong. Explicit assignments  good unless controls are dynamic